# Show Googlemap Zoom version of map on its infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, infowindow

here's the sample app.
http://www.yelp.com/map/the-codmother-fish-and-chips-san-francisco-2

I'm searching through googlemap's docs and found nothing
on putting the zoom version of the map on the infowindow, any ideas how to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

InfoWindow may contain any html code in its content. So, you basically need to initialize new google.maps.InfoWindow and set its contents to something like

```
<div id="myInnerMap"></div>
```

Further you bind new map or StreetView object to that div and setup it as you need.